# Why is an object with a read-only property assignable to a function parameter with a non-read-only property?

Tags: typescript

**TL;DR**: Why doesn't [this snippet](https://tsplay.dev/m0ezRW) cause a compiler error?

```
declare function setName(arg: { name: string }, newName: string): void

declare const fred: { readonly name: string }

setName(fred, 'George')
```

---

I was always thinking about types as sets of constraints. By defining a type, we narrow down the acceptable values from *literally any JavaScript value* to something more specific – a string, an array of numbers, an object with `name`, etc.

With this in mind, a `readonly` modifier would actually *remove* certain constraints, making the range of acceptable values wider. At least, this is how it works with arrays:

```
declare function countItems(array: readonly unknown[]): void
declare function removeLastItem(array: unknown[]): void

declare const immutableArray: readonly unknown[]
declare const mutableArray: unknown[]

countItems(immutableArray) // ✅
countItems(mutableArray) // ✅

removeLastItem(immutableArray) // ❌
removeLastItem(mutableArray) // ✅
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/wE28ZN).*

But when I tried to apply the same thinking to object properties, it didn't work:

```
function setName(arg: { name: string }, newName: string): void {
    arg.name = newName
}

interface Person {
    readonly name: string
}

const fred: Person = {
    name: 'Fred',
}

setName(fred, 'George') // ✅
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/NdDvkN).*

An object with a read-only property `name` is apparently acceptable when the function actually writes into this property.

**Why isn't this an error?**

Comment: The shape of Fred matches the shape of arg. Why not type arg as Person?

Comment: See the linked q/a for the answer to your question.  Note that `readonly` arrays are not the same as `readonly` properties despite both using the same keyword. A `ReadonlyArray` is a proper supertype of `Array` due to missing methods, and therefore they are not mutually assignable. But readonly properties and mutable properties are mutually assignable as per the other q/a.

Comment: @morganney They aren't the same